# Break regex up into words and everything else

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a specific set of words I'm interested in, let's say, `undefined` and `null`. I want to take a string, and split it into those words, and separately, the other stuff. So for example:

```
Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

For that, I'd like the result to be:

```
"Cannot convert ", "undefined", " or ", "null", " to object"
```

I'm having some difficulty constructing such a regex, any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Javascript regex you can use a capturing group to insert newlines before your keyword and then splitting by newlines:

```js
var str = 'Cannot convert undefined or null to object';
var arr = str.replace(/\b(undefined|null)\b/g, "\n$1\n").split(/\n/);

console.log(arr);
//=> ["Cannot convert ", "undefined", " or ", "null", " to object"]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aXomba/3)

Comment: This is very close, but I'd like to keep the spaces in the results. " or " instead of "or".

Comment: I am using JavaScript